# installing protobuf-compiler using yum in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: maven, protocol-buffers

I am trying to install protobuf-compiler for version 3.0 of protobuf as part of my pipeline. I am using the following command.

```
yum install -y protobuf-compiler-3.19.6-1.amzn2023.0.1.x86_64.rpm
```

I'm getting

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:05
$ yum install -y protobuf-compiler-3.19.6-1.amzn2023.0.1.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
12 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package protobuf-compiler-3.19.6-1.amzn2023.0.1.x86_64.rpm available.
```

I tried look on the amazon website to find details but got a bit stuck understanding the repo.